# Electric circuit with latex

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, pst-circ

I want to create below circuit but I am new to latex and I could'nt do it.How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{circuitikz}` `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}`...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372742/31034

Comment: You can also try to follow the first tutorial in the `circuitikz` manual at https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/. The symbol for the bulb is called `lamp` (same manual, around page 56).

Comment: @SAM have a look at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill[cyan!30](-0.5,-0.5)rectangle(9.5,6);
%\draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (10,10);
%\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {0\x}; }
%\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {0\y}; }
%  \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (9,5) to[nos,*-*,n=S1] (9,0)
node[circ] at (S1.e) {}
node[circ] at (S1.w) {};
\draw (6,0) to[battery1, color=blue!70!green!50, l=$5V$] (9,0);
\draw(6,0)--(0,0) -- (0,2.5) to[lamp,fill=yellow, l=$1W$] (4.5,2.5)to[lamp, fill=yellow,l=$1W$] (6,2.5) --(6,0);
\draw (9,5)to[lamp,fill=yellow, l_=$1$W](4,5)-|(3.75,2.5);
%\end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With using `siunitx` option (for corect notation of units), drawn in two loop as `circuitikz` picture (without scheme background fill):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (0,2) 
            to[lamp,l=1<\ohm>,fill=yellow] ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux1)
            to[lamp,l=1<\ohm>,fill=yellow] ++ (2,0) 
            -- ++ (0,-2)    coordinate (aux2)
            -- (0,0)
      (aux1)    -- ++ (0,2)
                to[lamp,l=1<\ohm>,fill=yellow] ++ (2,0) 
            -- ++ (2,0)     coordinate (aux3)
            to[nos,l=K]     (aux3 |- aux2)
            to[battery2, a=5<V>, color=cyan, invert] (aux2)
            ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In the case, that you like to have colored of the scheme background, than you need to add ˛in preamble of the above NWE (Minima Working Example)

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
```

and before of the end of scheme

```
\scoped[on background layer]
    \fill[olive!20, rounded corners=3mm]
    ([shift={(-3mm,-3mm)}] \cbb.south west) rectangle ([shift={(3mm,3mm)}] \cbb.north east);
```

Using this additions the scheme looks like this:

[image]