# How to vertically shift an arm of a cascode current mirror to make two different gate connections

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I need to make a connection like the red one without making short circuit with  the blue connection in the following circuit.

> In the answered question [Circuitikz Wire Kink Thingy When Wires Cross](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134067/circuitikz-wire-kink-thingy-when-wires-cross),both P1 and P2 are already shifted at x-axis "cascaded", but in my case the two mosfets M1 and M4 are y-axis shifted "cascoded".

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\draw
(0,0)     node[nmos] (nmos2) {}  node[right] at (nmos2) {M2}
(nmos2.G) node[nmos, xscale=-1, anchor=G] (nmos1) {} node[left] at (nmos1)         
{M1}  %below left,yshift=0.3cm
(nmos1.S) -- (nmos2.S) node[sground] {}
(nmos2.D) node[nmos, anchor=S] (nmos3) {} node[right] at (nmos3) {M3}
(nmos3.G) node[nmos, xscale=-1, anchor=G] (nmos4) {} node[left] at (nmos4)         
 {M4}

(nmos3.D) to[short] ++(0,2)
node[inputarrow,rotate=270] {} node [right,]{$i_{OUT}$} to[short] ++(0,0.5)
(nmos4.D) to[R,l=$R_1$,n=R1] ++(0,2)  to[short] ++(0,0.5)
node[inputarrow,rotate=270] {} node [left,]{$i_{IN}$} to[short] ++(0,0.5)

(nmos4.D) node[circ]    {} -| (nmos2.G) node[circ] {}
(R1) ++(0,1) node[circ] {} -| (nmos3.G) node[circ] {} 
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: Previous example]
[image: My Case]
[image: Target]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{circuitikz}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[node distance = 8mm and 16mm]
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
%
\draw (0,0) node (nmos1) [nmos, xscale=-1, label=left:M1]  {}
            node (nmos2) [nmos,right=of nmos1,label=right:M2] {}
(nmos1.G) to[short, -*]  (nmos2.G)
(nmos1.S) to[short, -*]  (nmos2.S)  node [sground] {}
%
(nmos1.D)   node (nmos3) [nmos, xscale=-1, anchor=S, label=left:M3] {}
(nmos2.D)   node (nmos4) [nmos, anchor=S, label=right:M4] {}
(nmos3.G) to[short,*- ]  (nmos4.G)
%
(nmos3.D) to[R=$R_1$,*-] ++ (0,2)   coordinate (R1)
                                    coordinate[above=of R1] (R+)

(R+)      to[short,o-*, i=$i_N$] (R1)
% blue and red connections
(nmos3.D) -| (nmos2.G)
(R1)      -| (nmos3.G)
%
(R1 -| nmos4.D) to[short,o-, i=$i_{OUT}$] (nmos4.D)
%
(nmos2.D) node[left] {$\frac{5}{0.25}$}
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```