# How to remove or minimize the resistance's terminals in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is their any way to remove the extension of the resistance's terminals?

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\draw
(0,0)     node[nmos] (nmos2) {}  node[right] at (nmos2) {M2}
(-3.5,0)  node[nmos, xscale=-1] (nmos1) {}  node[left] at (nmos1) {M1}

(nmos2.G) to[short] ++(-0.5,0) to[R,l=$R \SI{=1}{\kilo\ohm}$,n=R1] ++(-1,0)      
to (nmos1.G)

(nmos2.D) to[short] ++(0,0.5)
 node[inputarrow,rotate=270] {} node [right,]{$i_{OUT}$} to[short] ++(0,0.5)

(nmos1.D) to[short] ++(0,0.5)
node[inputarrow,rotate=270] {} node [left,]{$i_{IN}$}  to[short] ++(0,0.5)

(nmos1.S) to[short] ++(0,-0.5) -| (nmos2.S) ++(-1.75,-0.5) node[sground] {} 
(nmos1.D) node[circ] {} -| (nmos2.G) node[circ] {}
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: why you not consider answer on your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384515/? in it is used more simple and concise way how to draw electronic circuits ... and please help people here who wold be willing to help you and extend your code snippet to complete small document (mwe: minimal working example) beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from answer on [your question here](http://%20tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384515) to answer on this question is really small step:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{circuitikz}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[node distance = 8mm and 0mm]
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
%
\draw (0,0) node (nmos1) [nmos, xscale=-1, label=left:M1]  {}
(nmos1.G)   to[R=$R_1$,-*] ++ (1.5,0)
            node (nmos2) [nmos,right,label=right:M2] {}
coordinate[above=of nmos1.D] (in)
coordinate[above=of nmos2.D] (out)
(in)    to[short,o-*, i=$i_{IN}$]    (nmos1.D)
(out)   to[short,o- , i=$i_{OUT}$]   (nmos2.D)
(nmos1.D) -| (nmos2.G)
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

please, in future consider my comment above!